# using javascript:history.back() or server side back logic

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a new message page that can only be accessed if you are replying to a message or you click to message a user (unless of course you guess the URL). The cancel button currently will send you back to the previous page you were on using javascript:history.back().

I'm wondering if this is the best practice or if I should be using something on the server side to set where the cancel button takes you.

I took a look at this similar question: [Does using javascript:history.back(); have any unknown issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697956/does-using-javascripthistory-back-have-any-unknown-issues)

I don't understand the cache problem mentioned in that post or the javascript being disabled because the site has a lot of javascript that this feature would be the least of the concern if the user does not have javascript. I'm also not too worried about the user not having a page to go back to because as I said, this new message page can only be accessed by clicking on a button on a site unless you guess the URL or copy the URL into a new window.

I'm wondering if there's any other issues on doing it one way or another.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, one issue you did mention was when the user types in the URL? Maybe we're crazy, and/or hate buttons! Joking aside, using history.back is mainly frowned upon due to its static nature (who knows if there is a page to go back to).

What the guy is trying to say in the link you provided about caching is that, for example, say you had a sign in page. If you hit your button using history.back, the browser would use a cached version of the webpage, and in turn, clear out anything you filled in. It would also show that you weren't logged in on the users end.

If you do have server side logic. I think your best bet in this case would be to just put in an windows.location.href to your previous page. That way, this issue is resolved, and you know exactly where the user is going.